# Setting Custom RoI for OpenCV BoundryBox in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, video-tracking

I'm trying to implement Object Tracker using OpenCV and I'm new to Python. I'll call it from C# code via IronPython. What I'm trying to do, I want to set a custom rectangle as a parameter to Tracker instead of selecting it by mouse.

(Tracker code is the common example you can find on the internet)

Here is the problematic part :

This is how I set and create a rectangle

```
    initBB = cv2.rectangle(frame ,(154, 278),(173,183), (0, 255, 00),1)
```

This is Tracker's init method

```
tracker.init(frame, initBB)
```

and this is the error

> SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple

If I wanted to use "normal" way, initBB set would be like

```
        initBB = cv2.selectROI("Frame", frame, fromCenter=False,
        showCrosshair=False)
```

I couldn't see which part I'm doing wrong, am I trying to set the wrong type of object to initBB or setting it in wrong way?

Thanks! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error comes from a misunderstanding of what `cv2.rectangle` does.

It doesn't return a rectangle as you imagine. It is actually a drawing function. It draws the rectangle on the image you pass as argument and returns `None`.

A rectangle is just a tuple in Python with the following coordinates: `(start_col, start_row, width, height)`. You can create it without using an OpenCV function.

Comment: Thank you! For anyone who need help as an example its like ; initBB = (154, 278,173,183)